# How to iterate over the vector in Java and store only the specified class?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a use case where I need to iterate over the `Vector` elements and store the results in say array only if that instance is of class `method`

Are there any easy to do this?

Currently I'm doing this way :

```
    Iterator itr = vec.iterator();
    Iterator element = vec.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        boolean method = itr.next() instanceof Method;
        if(method)
            System.out.println( "\t" + ( (Method)(element.next()) ).name);
        else
            element.next();
    }
```

But I think there will be some better way than this.

Comment: Your boolean value `method` and a class named `method` is extremely confusing. Class names should **always** start uppercase.

Comment: `method` is conflicting things

Comment: What's the problem with this approach? You won't find any other way without using an external library like Guava. (Note: the else part should be removed, though)

Comment: Sorry about the `method` conflicts that was an typo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assume you have a class `Method`, then code could be something like :

```
    List<Method> list = new ArrayList<Method>();
    for (Object obj : vector) {
        if (obj instanceof Method) {
            list.add(obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Wasn't anyone concerned about iterating the Vector without synchronization?

If `vector` is not thread-confined, in the presence of another thread modifying its contents, the for-each iteration might throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: This is not an answer to a question but just a remark that can (probably should) be added to any answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can invoke the `.stream()` method that returns a stream of the vector elements, so storing the elements, for example in a list, can be done by invoking a Collector

```
Vector<String> vec = new Vector<>();
vec.add("hello");
vec.add("world");

List<String> list = vec.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```