# What are different ways to iterate through a vector, other than the iterator object?

Tags: java, vector, iterator

This function here takes a vector of single digit elements, converts the vector into a whole number, increments that number, and then reconverts that incremented number into a vector and returns it.

**Here the function :**

```
public static Vector<Integer> plusOne(Vector<Integer> digits) {
        int dig=0;
        Iterator it=digits.iterator();
        Vector<Integer>res=new Vector<Integer>();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            dig=(dig*10)+((int)it.next());
        }
        dig=dig+1;
        //System.out.println(dig);
        while(dig!=0)
        {
            int temp=dig%10;
            res.add(temp);
            dig=dig/10;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

**My question :** Are there any alternate ways to traverse through the vector instead of using the iterator object

Comment: You can use for each loop: `for(int i : digits){/* code */}`

Comment: And hint. you see downvotes because it seems you didnt bother to do prior research. There are various questions on this place that answer your question already ... like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778441/how-to-iterate-over-the-vector-in-java-and-store-only-the-specified-class

Comment: Kevin's Razor (a rule of thumb I invented just now): The answer to any question that begins "Are there any alternate ways..." is nearly always "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Enhanced for loop to iterate over a vector

```
 for (Integer digit : digits) {   

 }
```

We also know the size of the vector, we can write a for loop using `vector.size()`.

```
 for(int index = 0; index < digits.size(); index++) {      
   System.out.println(digits.get(index));
 }
```

You can also follow the other ways given [here](http://javainsimpleway.com/vector-with-looping/)

Comment: Note that the enhanced for loop is just syntactical sugar for iterating with iterator ....